# Colored border of the transparent color key around text written on the transparent window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, drawing, gdi+, layered-windows

I created a Transparent Layered window with a color key that I use to make the window transparent.
So far it works all fine.
Writing text on it - using GDI+ - works, too...

The problem I encounter is, that the text has a thin border of the colorkey-color around the letters...

What I do in the WM_PAINT is:

```
1. Clear the drawing area Graphics::Clear(ColorKey);
2. Draw the text on it.
```

Screenshot of what i mean:  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/709/cutp.jpg/

Anyone knows about how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `Graphics::SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintSingleBitPerPixelGridFit)`.

Comment: It works -why?...And what if I wanted to use The AntiAlias-Mode?

Comment: Antialiasing causes the background to be blended with the edges of the character - this is why your key color bleeds through. Unfortunately this means it's completely incompatible with color keying, you'll have to use a different technique to define your transparency if you want antialiasing.

Comment: Do you got a suggestion or hint in the direction for which method to use?... 

How about a custom blend function?

Comment: I don't know enough about transparent layered windows to be sure, but you could start by using a RGBA graphic which defines transparency as an attribute of each pixel.